# C: How can I alter which register a variable writes to?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

C newbie here, wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of some reading material to solve this problem. I have 2 registers and a variable:

```
Register->Foo;
Register->Bar;
myVar;
```

`myVar` is the output of a math function, and the result gets written repeatedly to `Register->Foo` for many cycles, then when a button is pressed, `myVar` gets written repeatedly to `Register->Bar` for many cycles.

Currently, I'm doing a check every cycle, like so:

```
if button not pressed:
    write myVar to Register->Foo
else
    write myVar to Register->Bar
```

But I only really need to do a check whenever the button is pressed, not every instruction cycle. How can I change where myVar points to only on a button press, and have that setting stick for all cycles until the button is pressed again? Is something like this possible?

```
OutputRegister = myVar // have this run all the time inside a loop

// somewhere else
OutputRegister = Register->Foo or Register->Bar 
// depending on button
// What data structure or method can I use to make this!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep a pointer to the correct location. That way you can assign to it and change the destination on some other trigger.

For example:

```
int foo;
int bar;
int * dest;

void on_button_press() {
    dest = &bar;
}

void on_button_release() {
    dest = &foo;
}

void main() {
    for (;;) {
        // code
        *dest = myVar;
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this, this seems to be exactly what I want.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I don't have enough rep to upvote you but will soon!

Answer (score 0):

You use an extra variable, e.g. `is_assigned`. When the button is pressed it's set to zero (meaning "false"), then you change the condition and assignments like this:

```
if (button_not_pressed && !is_assigned)
{
    if (button_not_pressed)
        Register->Foo = myVar;
    else
        Register->Bar = myVar;

    is_assigned = 1;
}
```

This means that when `button_not_pressed` is true, and `is_assigned` is false, then do the statements inside. As `is_assigned` is then set to true, the next iteration the condition will be false.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! My question was not entirely clear however. I added more details for what I'm trying to do. I think jleahy's answer might be what I'm looking for?

Comment: @patches It seems like that answer is more in line with what you want.

Comment: Yes it was. But yours was helpful too :P